# How to ignore changes in leading/trailing whitespace in a non-diff editor?

Tags: diff, visual-studio-code, vscode-git

With `"diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false`, changes in a **diff** editor:

[image]

With `"diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": true`, changes in a **diff** editor:

[image]

With `"diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": true`, changes in a normal (**non-diff**) editor:

[image]

How to ignore changes in leading/trailing whitespace in a **non-diff** editor as well?

Comment: Git has no concept of a "diff editor" or "non-diff editor", but if you are talking about the `git diff` *command*, it has a `-w` flag and some finer-grained flags for controlling how whitespace changes are handled. I think, though, that you mean this question to be specific to visual studio code *only*, in which case, you should remove the [tag:git] and [tag:git-diff] tags.

Comment: @torek Thanks for pointing out, it's a question of the vscode and git integration, I've removed the `git-diff` tag.

Comment: It looks like you are referring to the `SCM: Diff Decorations` settings.  I don't see a setting for ignoring whitespace in those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For others, your issue has been closed with a fix, see [Add option to ignore changes in trim whitespace in quick diff](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130956)
.

The new setting is:

`SCM: Diff Decorations Ignore Trim Whitespace`

> Controls whether leading and trailing whitespace is ignored in Source
> Control diff gutter decorations.

Options:

1. `true`: Ignore leading and trailing whitespace
2. `false`: Do not ignore leading and trailing whitespace (default)
3. `inherit`: Inherit from `diffEditor.IgnoreTrimWhitespace`

This new setting is working in the Insiders' Build (and so may be out in v1.63) - it only affects whether those scm gutter decorations appear when they are caused by leading or trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add that if you'd like to quickly toggle ignoring leading/trailing whitespace, you could use the setting `"scm.diffDecorationsIgnoreTrimWhitespace": "inherit"` and assign a shortcut for `toggle.diff.ignoreTrimWhitespace`, I'm using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Show Leading/Trailing Whitespace Differences" button on the top right corner in the diff view.See below image
[image]

[image]

Comment: The question is "How to ignore changes in leading/trailing whitespace in a **non-diff** editor?"